# Will an HTML embed code still work if the main website it is coming from is being taken down?

Tags: html, cross-domain, embed, transfer

I have this embed code: <iframe width="100%" height="1000" src="https://connect.akclub.com/embedOndemand" ( it goes on)

The website https://connect.akclub.com is being taken down, so I am working on transferring a lot of its content to another platform, using embed codes. However I am unsure that once the site is down, the embed code will no longer work. Is this true, if so is there a solution to this? When transferring content (such as videos, schedules, ect.) what process do you use?

Answer (score 0):

No. Once a website is offline, it's content cannot be rendered and is no longer available.